# Is the camera permission automatically handled by iOs?

Tags: ios, ios-camera

I'm building an app for iOs 8.0+ which gives user the ability to choose a photo from his gallery or from his camera. I'm just wondering if I need to programmatically "ask" the user for the permission to access to his gallery or camera or if it's automatically handled by iOs.

For now, in my app, even if I uninstall / reinstall it, I'm never prompted by a dialog to ask for any permissions. Maybe I got one at the beginning, when I started to work on this app, I don't remember... But I have never integrated any code which asks for any permission to the user. Can you tell me if I need to change anything ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you open the gallery, the app asks the user for permission for one time, however many times you you open it, then if you uninstall and install back it will ask you one time again.

1- the iOS handles the permission dialogues.
2- if the user uses a features that requires a permission the OS handles the permission request with a dialogue.

Answer (score 1):

At the time when app is going to access camera, iOS ask for permission to allow for it or not. Once you granted permission it will not ask again. When you uninstall app and install it again, iOS ask for permission again on first time use.

You can check granted permissions to app into Settings. To view permissions, go to Settings from home page -> scroll down to your application and select it -> this will list all permissions requested by app and granted by you. You can alter permission from here too.

If you wish, you can ask user to grant permission to access camera before calling camera feature in source code.